# How to modify title tag in a plugin?

Tags: title, wp-title

I would like to add a meta value to the title `<title>` tag in a custom post typed page. So there would be meta value before normal post title. I have a custom field created that contains the needed data, but I don't know how to show it in the `<title>`. I can show it in pages `<h1>` in a template file, but I need the title tag to start with that data.

How to do this? My theme uses `<?php wp_head(); ?>` and `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` to print title.

Comment: I think you are confused, o maybe I don't fully understand your question. Do you refer to document tilte (`<title>` element, what you see in browser tabs) o the title of the post you see in the within the page?

Comment: I guess you are talking about custom field value to be concatenated with the page title. Can you please, at least, show us how do you create this custom field and how do you output the page title.

Comment: Updated question. Question refers to <title> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I actually ended up doing was to use filter document_title_parts.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/

I just unshifted a value to the array. I don't think the documentation actually is very clear about that.

And this method still don't work with Yoast SEO installed.